# Client side s3 upload and returning the public url of the image

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am writing a client side image uploader library for python. I need to upload an image to Amazon S3 and return the public URL of the image. I can do this using BOTO however I have to share my Secret Key which is not the correct way of doing it. As an alternative, I can use Browser upload using Amazon's POST request but that doesn't give me access to the image's public URL. How do I solve this conundrum?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. The only thing I have found is to make the image public on save and later use:

```
item.image.url.split('?')[0]
```

to get the URL.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) module to get the URL without the query parameters?